# Adding sound java

Tags: java, audio

I want to add a sound in a frame I made.
I googled it and I found that Java doesn't support mp3 so I converted a song in my disk to a wav file.
After impoting sun.audio.* and java.io.* in my project, I add these lines in the frame constructor

```
    File xx = new File("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\oss.wav");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(xx);
    AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in); 
    AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
```

but it doesn't work, I'm not sure what is the problem and I hope someone of you can help me to figure it out.

Comment: I'm beginner here, here is the error message:

 Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
 Access restriction: The type 'AudioStream' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar') and few other lines

Comment: Can you post the full exception stack trace within your answer? Use the __edit__ feature. Thanks. :)

Comment: the error message is too long,, here it is:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10552402_312115595619279_6152313424296453681_n.jpg?oh=ff1013fa17fb0e4b09eb66dcb9accefc&oe=5433E9DD&__gda__=1413071188_d55a02c5c4843ce5e103f82d8eaca455

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146973/starting-and-stopping-music-in-background/21147304#21147304)

Comment: Are you trying to do this from an applet?

Comment: **don't post links to off site resources, they good dead and aren't any use to anyone else** post what was asked for here or this will get closed ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

[You receive errors for unresolved compilation errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665946/adding-sound-java#comment38240144_24665946) You're not handling Checked `Exception` Types where you should be.

```
try {
    File xx = new File("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\oss.wav");
      // Must handle FileNotFoundException from new File()!
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(xx);
    AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
    try {
        AudioPlayer.player.start(as); // Must handle IOException from start()!
    }
    catch (IOException ex) { /* Ignore? */ }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { /* Ignore? */ }
```

Read more:

- [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation @ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.htm